# CSS Container Position

Tags: html, css

Can anyone explain the behavior of the container? Without borders appears interval at the top (What's this? Padding of body or html? Margin of inner container?) And no interval with borders.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: #999;
}
#wrap {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*border:1px solid red;*//*On/Off uncomment*/
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: could you please reproduce the  issue in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `<p>` has a margin by default. if you want the container to be attached to the top you have to remove it with the following CSS:

```
p { margin:0; }
```

Or if you want to keep the margin of the `<p>` but inside the container you have to use the following CSS rule:

```
#wrap { overflow:hidden; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This margin is because of the margin-top you have on the `<p>` element. The easy solution to include this space in the `<body>` is to use padding instead of margin:

```
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 16px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `<p>` element margin

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: #999;
}
#wrap {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*border:1px solid red;*//*On/Off uncomment*/
}

#wrap p{
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```